# How to calculate the value of the boxes px?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

Total width of the bar = 500px, red box = 1, yellow box = 1, green box = 2,

CSS:

```
.box { 
        float:left;
        width:150px;
        box-shadow:3px 3px 2px #666767;
        height:30px; 
    }
.red { 
        background-color:#ff0000;
        width:150px;                
    }
.yellow {           
        background-color:#ffff00; 
        width:200px;
        }
.green {
        background-color:#00ff00;
        width:50px;
        }
```

HTML Code :

```
content += "<div class=\"box-container\">
               <div class=\"box red\">
               </div>

               <div class=\"box yellow\">
               </div>

               <div class=\"box green\">
               </div>
            </div>
         </br>";
```

From this I want to calculate the Width of the box in px for the redbox, yellowbox and greenbox.

Comment: You mean that in this case Redbox should be 25% in width, Yellow- 25% and Green 50%?

Comment: That depends on the box-sizing (content-box, border-box), and the margins and padding you want to have.

Comment: @ArunKumarMk The question is not clear. You need to share some code. Your *PX* is nothing but `height and width` of a element.

Comment: By **PX** do you mean the **Height or/and Width** of those boxes? Does the **Red**, **Yellow**, and **Green** boxes have any IDs or Classes? You can calculate the Dimensions `height & width` of those Boxes if you have a way of accessing them or since the Boxes seem of equal width; it is logical to infer that they are each 33.33333~% of the total width which should be around: 165px each (width). However, following the smart thoughts of  @SebastianKaczmarek; Red could be: 25% of 500=125px, Yellow could be: 25% of 500=125px, and Green could be: 50% of 500=250px — all widths. Be a little clearer.

Comment: Additionally, you can't also set any style on a DOM Element without an Identifier or any handle with which to pin-point the exact Node you are targeting. You may copy/paste the HTML Code that generated the Boxes you referred to at https://i.stack.imgur.com/0K2TD.png  Like that it is easier to assist you.

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer, I have added the code above and I mean the width of the boxes, updated my questions with the css class details.

Answer (score 1):

You can find width of box following way using JQuery.

```js
width1 = $(".red").width();
width2 = $(".yellow").width();
width3 = $(".green").width();

totalWidth = width1 + width2 + width3;
alert(totalWidth);
```

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #666767;
  height: 30px;
}

.red {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  width: 150px;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: #ffff00;
  width: 200px;
}

.green {
  background-color: #00ff00;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-container">
  <div class="box red"></div>
  <div class="box yellow"></div>
  <div class="box green"></div>
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3Laww37/)

Answer (score 1):

I made a few changes to the html and css because it didn't seem to work for me, but [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BQLReZ?editors=1111) is a console.log with the right px values.

```
  <div class="box">
    <div id="red" class="color">
    </div>

    <div id="yellow" class="color">
    </div>

    <div id="green" class="color">
    </div>
   </div>
```

CSS

```
.box { 
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    background-color: white 0;
    box-shadow:3px 3px 2px grey;
    height:30px; 
 }    
#red { 
    background-color:red;
    width:25%; 
    height:100%;
        float: left;
 }
#yellow {           
    background-color:yellow; 
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    }
#green {
    background-color: #00ff00;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    }
```

Javascript

```
 function getWidth(){
   var redWidth = $("#red").width();
   var greenWidth = $('#green').width();
   var yellowWidth = $('#yellow').width();
   console.log(redWidth, yellowWidth, greenWidth);
 }
 getWidth();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var redWidth = document.getElementsByClassName("red").offsetWidth;
var yellowWidth = document.getElementsByClassName("yellow").offsetWidth;
var greenWidth = document.getElementsByClassName("green").offsetWidth;
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the simple calculations and set the value for the width.

```
var totalIssues = args.chart.chartWidth[i].redWidth + args.chart.chartWidth[i].yellowWidth + args.chart.chartWidth[i].greenWidth; 
            var red = (args.chart.chartWidth[i].redWidth/totalIssues)*100;
            var yellow = (args.chart.chartWidth[i].yellowWidth/totalIssues)*100;
            var green = (args.chart.chartWidth[i].greenWidth/totalIssues)*100;

            var totalPx = 300; 

            var redWid = (red/100) * 500;
            var yellowWid = (yellow/100) * 500;
            var greenWid = (green/100) * 500;


            console.log("Red Width : " + redWid + "Yellow Width : "+ yellowWid+ "Green Width : "+greenWid);
            content += "<div class=\"project-data\"><div class=\"box-container"+i+"\"><div class=\"box"+i+" red" +i+ "\"></div><div class=\"box"+i+" yellow" +i+ "\"></div><div class=\"box"+i+" green" +i+ "\"></div></div></br>"; 
             content += "<style type=\"text/css\"> ";
             content +=".box-container"+i+"{ margin: 50;}";
             content +=".box"+i+"{float: left; width:150px; box-shadow:3px 3px 2px #666767; height:20px;}";
             content += ".red" +i+" { width: " + redWid + "px; background-color:#ff0000; }";
             content += ".yellow"+i+" { width: " + yellowWid + "px; background-color:#ffff00;  }";
             content += ".green"+i+" { width: " + greenWid + "px; background-color:#00ff00; }";      
             content +=  "</style> </br>";
```